# List top-level directories with file count

Tags: python

I need to show the total file count for all top-level directories, including the ones that have a file count of zero. Each top-level directory can contain subdirectories. I need the total count listed next to top-level directory only.

```
cnt = 0 

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(FILES):
    filecount = len(files)
    cnt += filecount
    print(dirnames,": ",filecount)
```

How can I get the above to print something like:

- top-level-dir1: 234
- top-level-dir2: 0
- top-level-dir3: 5
- ....etc.

So, total files, including what's in the nested subfolders, but print the total next to the top-level folders only.

```
for directory in os.listdir(DOCUMENTS):
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        filecount = 0
        for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(directory):
            filecount += len(files)
    print(directory,": ",filecount)
```

I'm close, but this just shows file count as 1 for each.

Comment: Do an `os.listdir` at the top level, and do individual `os.walk` calls for each member that is a directory.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I'm close but I'm missing something. Could you look at my update?

Comment: `if os.path.isdir(directory):` would be a big help.  Also, you need to initialize `filecount` OUTSIDE of the inner loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm still missing something. Still just printing whatever I initialize `filecount` or `cnt` to.

Comment: I updated your update to show the proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the `filecount` variable for each directory. Instead, you want the count to persist over each directory in `CONTRACTS`.

Also, `os.listdir(CONTRACTS)` only shows the immediate directory names in CONTRACTS; for the script to work in directories other than the current directory, you need to use `os.path.join()` to specify the full path when you call `os.walk()`.

Finally, as @TimRoberts says, you should use `os.path.isdir()` to check the output of `os.listdir()`, as it can also return files.

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
import os

target = "target_directory"

for dir_name in os.listdir(target):
    dir_path = os.path.join(target, dir_name)
    if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
        file_count = 0
        for _, _, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            file_count += len(files)
        print(f"{dir_name}: {file_count}")
```

Comment: Still printing 1 for each. It's like it's counting the subdirs, not all the files nested in the subdirs.

Comment: It's listing the correct subdirectories but it says each one has 1 file in it.

Comment: My answer was assuming that you are listing files in the current directory. I have fixed it so that it can list files in other directories as well.

Comment: Updated again with @TimRoberts suggestion to use os.path.isdir to check the output from os.listdir.

Comment: The first version worked the way I was hoping, this version includes the full path. Just wanted the first folders as before.

Comment: Can I see the previous version?

Comment: I changed the redefinition of `directory` to `fullpath`, then called `directory` in the print statement and that resolved my issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer with something similar so that only the short directory name is printed.